# Java: Using File & Buffered Reader to fill an Array

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader, filereader

So, I have my first Java project due in my new course this Sunday. One of the (most important) things we need to do is to fill 2 arrays with information read from a file. My professor said to use a file and buffered reader to do this.
Unfortunately, I've never used either.

For the first array I need to: Create a String array with 15 elements, then Read the state search data from the data file and store each item into the array.
The filename is 'states.search.txt' and contains the following.

```
California
Texas
AK
California
Indiana
Missippi
Jacksonville
Okalahooma
Florida
Maine
Hawaii
Puerto_Rico
FL
New_York
Auburn
```

The 2nd array is a lot more involved, so I'll ask separately for that one.
All help is appreciated!

Comment: "help" != "do this for me" which is pretty much what you're asking. Oracle provides tutorials as I'm sure your class materials do (and of course, the class itself). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: Do your own homework.  If this is too hard to do yourself, pick another field of study.  The world already has enough programmers who are terrible at programming.

Comment: Here's the File API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html And here's the BufferedReader API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html Now you have the information to do it yourself.

Comment: Google it, you will learn how to do file handling . or see this link http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read lines from file follow:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
       List<String> states = new ArrayList(15)<>; // ArrayList is superstructure over array
       FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\states.search.txt");
       String state; 
       while ((state = br.readLine()) != null) {
           states.add(state);
       }
       in.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
 }
```

But you have to turn on your brain to do your home work, it's better for you.